# ssd issue: cannot create new partitions

Tags: arch-linux, ssd, smartctl, testdisk, cfdisk

I have an external ssd that had archlinux installed. It refused to boot so I tried plugging the ssd into another computer. When I tried to mount the ext4 partition it said there were issues and that it needed cleaning, so i ran the `fsck` command. The command ran for a long time and with my shitty luck I got a power outage while the command was still running.

Now when I run `fdisk -l` I still see the device but it cannot list the partitions. Using advices from chatgpt I installed `testdisk` in order the salavage what I could. The program could not recover anything nor detect any partition from the drive. At that point I just gave up on recovering anything and I just wanted to be able to use the drive again.

I ran the `cfdisk /dev/sdb` to create new partitions. After that I checked using `fdisk -l` but no partition were listed. I tried again making sure I did write the changes before exiting the tool but no partition were created. I tried to create a partition using `fdisk` instead of `cfdisk` but it provides the same result.

Still following chatgpt advices, I tried to check the state of the ssd using `smartctl /dev/sdb -d scsi -a` which outputs me:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Sony
Product:              Storage
Revision:             2210
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        240.057.409.536 bytes [240 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Logical Unit id:      0x502b2a201d1c1b1a
Serial number:        459C7B0102F8
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Fri Jun 23 17:03:04 2023 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Disabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Request Sense failed, [Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente]
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

But if I rerun the command directly after I get:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Sony
Product:              Storage
Revision:             2210
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        240.057.409.536 bytes [240 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Logical Unit id:      0x502b2a201d1c1b1a
Serial number:        459C7B0102F8
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Fri Jun 23 17:05:53 2023 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Disabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

From here I checked the archwiki for the [S.M.A.R.T component](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.) and ran some commands:

To enable smart on the device: `sudo smartctl --smart=on -d scsi /dev/sdb` which outputs me:

```
=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
Informational Exceptions (SMART) disabled
Temperature warning disabled
```

To launch a test: `smarctl -c -d scsi /dev/sdb` which outputs me something different [from the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.#Run_a_test):

```
SCSI device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information
```

Please note that I have to specify the `-d scsi` flag (I assume it is scsi and not nvme, I tried both and with nvme it could not find the controller) to make the command work or I would automatically get:

```
/dev/sdb: Unknown USB bridge [0x054c:0x0aa4 (0x6607)]
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

chargpt advised me to update the firmware. I never did anything of the like and I'm not sure if it was some hallucinations from the AI so I checked [the device page on Sony's website](https://www.sony.be/fr/electronics/support/external-hdd-ssd-external-ssd/sl-bg2) but it says "No more software downloads for certain storage devices" so i guess it's a dead end anyway...

In the end I still don't know if this is a device issue or just me doing thing incorrectly. If someone has any idea or any command I could try to further check I'd be interrested.